# Object from javascript need to get data out of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

It seems that the ajax call is pulling data back in which

**The data looks like this:**

```
Object {oms_tcall_k: 336501, locatn_k: 0, folderowner: "bdmiller", tc_type: null, tc_date: null}
```

I want to get store value of things into variables

var myfolderowner =  data.folderowner   ( value is "bdmiller")

However, I'm getting **undefined** when getting at the data

I am doing a **JSON.stringify**

```
data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
```

Is this data not in the correct format?   **data[0] works to show it ALL**

```
console.log(data.folderowner);  //undefined
console.log(data["folderowner"]); //undefined
console.log(data["FOLDEROWNER"]); //undefined
console.log(data[0]);  //Object {oms_tcall_k: 336501, locatn_k: 0, folderowner: "bdmiller", tc_type: null, tc_date: null}
console.log(data[0][0]); //undefined
```

Comment: can you try to log this? `console.log( data[0].folderowner );`

Comment: Ok, that worked  `console.log( data[0].folderowner );`   but why doesn't this work  `console.log(data.folderowner);`

Comment: looks like data is an array. your object is the first (and only) element of the array, hence data[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON.stringfy will actually change it from an object to a string. Therefore, the stringified version will look like this:

```
'{"oms_tcall_k": "336501", "locatn_k": "0", "folderowner": "bdmiller", "tc_type": "null", "tc_date": "null"}'
```

That's why when you do data[0] it returns the whole string. If you want to access the object, I would not stringfy the data. Then you should be able to get the value like this:

```
var folderOwner = data["folderowner"]; //Should return "bdmiller"
```

Comment: Did you remove the Json.stringfy(data) and try it? If it is a string, then yes that will be undefined. change -data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null  to - data: data ? data : null

Comment: Looks the same    `data: data`   AND   `data ? JSON.parse(data) : null`  AND  `data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null`  Seems to all look the same

Comment: What does console.log(data) look like for all 3??

Comment: [Object]  0: Object
folderowner: "bdmiller"
locatn_k: 0
oms_tcall_k: 336501
tc_date: null
tc_type: null
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: so it looks like it's an array where the [0] data point is the object.  You should be able to access it like this then: var folderOwnder = data[0]["folderowner"];

Comment: console.log(data[0].folderowner);

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `stringify` you should use `parse` to convert string to JSON

```
data =  data ? JSON.parse(data) : null
```

```js
var text = '{"oms_tcall_k": 336501, "locatn_k": 0, "folderowner": "bdmiller", "tc_type": null, "tc_date": null}';

var data = JSON.parse(text);
console.log(data.oms_tcall_k)
```

Comment: Same results I'm seeing

Comment: JSON.parse(data)  and JSON.stringify(data) and plain  data    ALL look the same , it must be the format of the data?

Comment: Code snippet is not changing it, plus it is   :  not =

Answer (score 0):

If you actually did JSON.stringify(data), then the data would be a string, and that wouldn't make sense.

According to your findings, data is an array, and the actual data object you want is in the first element of that array. So either fix the back end serving the data, or (hackily), data = data[0] before your data calls...

Comment: Ya, I was changing the Web Api calls in the way the server spits back the data with  `  return Ok(troubleCallModels);` which is `IHttpActionResult` that is returned to me